# Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: java, ssl, kubernetes, fabric8

I am using the fabric8 java API to connect to a remote kubernetes cluster from java. However it fails with the following exception

```
DEBUG [2015-10-26 17:11:11,270] io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.KubernetesHelper: Address does not appear to be SSL-enabled - falling back to http
! javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

How do I make sure that java connects to http and not https? I am using Dropwizard as the http server. Is this a property taht can be set for this server? Or this is something that needs to be configured on the kubernetes master?

This is how I create the connection object

`KubernetesClient kubernetes = new KubernetesClient (new KubernetesFactory(MASTER))`;

```
where MASTER = "http://myMaster:8080";
```

http://keithtenzer.com/2015/05/04/kubernetes-container-orchestration-through-java-apis/